# On Dashboard: Can the videos be filtered on statuses?

Tags: zalenium

On zalenium Dashboard, Can the videos be filtered based on Passed/Failed/Timeout statuses ?

Comment: I know, there is a way to search the videos based on 'Passed', 'Failed', 'Completed' keywords. But, my question is: do we have any option wherein if we select/click on status keyword in above panel, the videos should get filtered out.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type your search term in the search box, which also includes test statuses.

Comment: I know, there is a way to search the videos based on 'Passed', 'Failed', 'Completed' keywords. But, my question is: do we have any option wherein if we select/click on status keyword in above panel, the videos should get filtered out.?

Comment: No, that precisely does not exist. The only option so far is to use the search box.